# Pandigital Regex?

Tags: regex

What's a regular expression that validates if a string is pandigital (containing all digits from 1 to 9 exactly once)?

For example:

```
123456789
891364572
```

But not:

```
11234556789
25896471
```

I know how to do this without regex but I was unable to form a regex for it.

Thanks.

This is not homework.

Comment: This is not what REs are for - you need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short and sweet, using a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*([1-9]).*\1)[1-9]{9}$/
```

- `[1-9]` is the character class for nonzero digits - equivalent to `[123456789]`
- `.*` matches any string of any length.
- `.*([1-9]).*\1.*` matches any string with that contains at least two occurrences of the same nonzero digit

  - a nonzero digit is matched and captured by `([1-9])`
  - a repeat of that nonzero digit is matched by `\1`, a **back-reference** to the first captured match.
  - the `.*` matches the arbitrary padding before, and between the nonzero digit and its repeat.
- `(?!<pattern>)` matches any position where the contained pattern *doesn't* match.  This is a **negative lookahead**, as it only matches a *position* in the string, and doesn't consume any of it - just looks ahead to compare it with the contained pattern.
- `[1-9]{9}` matches nine nonzeo digits.

  - `<pattern>{9}` means match the preceding pattern 9 times.
- `^<pattern>$` matches any string that exactly matches the contained pattern (rather than contains a substring that matches the pattern)

  - `^` matches the position at the beginning of a string OR the beginning of a line
  - `$` matches the position at the end of a string OR the end of a line

So combined, we check to make sure that it's not repeating any digits, then we check that it's only digits.  Since it's 9 digits long, and none repeat, all must show up exactly once.  That's the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) at work!

The syntax for your specific regular expression engine may vary.  The above is a [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE) (supported in Perl, Ruby, and a bunch of different other languages). [Posix regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX) have slightly different syntax.  Not all engines support negative lookaheads, but most support back-references. Neither are part of the definition of formal theoretic regular expressions, but are very convenient.

Comment: +1 for a succinct answer with great explanation, but I'd still stick with the non-regex approach for readability.

Answer (score 4):

Regex is not exactly the best tool for the job here, but here you go:

```
^(?=[^1]*1[^1]*$)(?=[^2]*2[^2]*$)(?=[^3]*3[^3]*$)(?=[^4]*4[^4]*$)(?=[^5]*5[^5]*$)(?=[^6]*6[^6]*$)(?=[^7]*7[^7]*$)(?=[^8]*8[^8]*$)(?=[^9]*9[^9]*$)[1-9]+$
```

`(?= )` is a look-ahead. It does not actually fit the description of regular expressions, as it does not describe a regular language.

Comment: That looks much more complicated than my existing solution.. perhaps regex isn't the tool I thought it was..

Comment: +1 for the good advice, -1 for making my eyes bleed :-) [No, seriously, just +1]

Answer (score 2):

If it's not homework, you shouldn't be using REs. The following C code should be a good start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isPandigital (char *inputStr) {
    /* Initial used states of false. */
    char used[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    /* Process each character in string. */

    while ((ch = *inputStr++) != '\0') {
        /* Non-numeric, bad. */
        if ((ch < '0') || (ch > '9')) {
            return 0;
        }

        /* Too many, bad. */
        if (++count > 9) {
            return 0;
        }

        /* Multiples, bad. */
        if (used[ch - '0']) {
            return 0;
        }

        /* Store fact that this one's been used. */
        used[ch - '0'] = 1;
    }

    /* Good or bad depending on how many we've had. */
    return (count == 9);
}
```

```
int main (int argCount, char *argVar[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argCount; i++) {
        if (isPandigital (argVar[i])) {
            printf ("'%s' is pandigital\n", argVar[i]);
        } else {
            printf ("'%s' is NOT pandigital\n", argVar[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using your test data:

```
$ pandigital 123456789 891364572 11234556789 25896471
```

we get the following results:

```
'123456789' is pandigital
'891364572' is pandigital
'11234556789' is NOT pandigital
'25896471' is NOT pandigital
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with REs, they're just not suitable to *every* task.

Comment: I don't know... rampion's solution looks pretty elegant if it actually works. I'm not familiar with regexps, so I couldn't say. But his breakdown of the expression seems to make sense.

Comment: Hmm much longer than my existing solution, and I don't know C so I can't test it out.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier to do in procedural code, looping through each character and marking them off in an array, ... or is this some homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool chk(string s, int idx, set sofar) {
  return index == s.length ? true : isdigit(s[idx]) && !sofar.count(s[idx]) && chk(s,++idx,sofar.insert(s[idx]));
}
```

something like this could work. haven't been bothered checking it.